# Scroll down script for appium version 1.7 other than scrollTo, Touchoption, Swipe

Tags: appium, ui-select, android-uiautomator

Please find the below script is not working for scroll down based on text "English" in appium.

String Scrollviewcontainer="new UiSelector().resourceId(\"com.eterno:id/parent_onboarding_language_container\")";
String scrollelement="new UiSelector().text(\"English\")";

driver.findElement(MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(" + Scrollviewcontainer + ")" + ".scrollIntoView(" + scrollelement + ")"));

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator(
                "new UiScrollable(new UiSelector()).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().text(\"English\"));");
```

Comment: @veerapathiran have you tried using above solution?